# I am prepared permit EIP712, but tx "Reverted", function selector 'Reverted 0x08c379a

Tags: web3js, web3.py, python, eip712

I'm trying to send a permit for a transaction, but I get a function call mismatch return if I call through the smartcontract token function. If I call via encodeABI and add the same arguments, I don't see the message in the transaction. I use the following code

```
    def build_permit(owner, spender, value, deadline, web3):
    data = {
        "types": {
            "EIP712Domain": [
                {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
                {"name": "version", "type": "string"},
                {"name": "chainId", "type": "uint256"},
                {"name": "verifyingContract", "type": "address"},
            ],
            "Permit": [
                {"name": "owner", "type": "address"},
                {"name": "spender", "type": "address"},
                {"name": "value", "type": "uint256"},
                {"name": "nonce", "type": "uint256"},
                {"name": "deadline", "type": "uint256"},
            ],
        },
        "domain": {
            "name": "TestToken", 
            "version": "1",
            "chainId": 4,
            "verifyingContract": address_token,
        },
        "primaryType": "Permit",
        "message": {
            "owner": owner,
            "spender": spender,
            "value": value,
            "nonce": web3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_account.address),
            "deadline": deadline,
        },
    }

    return encode_structured_data(data)

def test_permit():
    signer = my_account
    owner = my_account.address
    holder = signer.address
    address_token = SC.USDT("RINKEBY")
    spender = SC.ROUTER('RINKEBY')
    deadline = int(time.time()) + 3600
    #print(deadline)
    amount = web3.toWei(1, 'ether')
    usdt = token_contract(address_token,web3n(RINKEBY))
    permit = build_permit(owner, spender, amount, deadline,web3n(RINKEBY))
    signed = signer.sign_message(permit)
    tx = usdt.functions.permit(holder, spender, 1000000000000000000, int(time.time()) + 3600,  signed.v, Web3.toBytes(signed.r), Web3.toBytes(signed.s)).call()
```

**Why does the beginning of the data start with a different function and how do I get the correct signature?**

```
response = {'error': {'code': 3, 'data': '0x08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000...207369676e61747572650000', 'message': 'execution reverted: ERC20Permit: invalid signature'}, 'id': 1, 'jsonrpc': '2.0'}
```

**Smartcontract ABI 0x77c24f0Af71257C0ee26e0E0a108F940D1698d53**

```
[
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "string",
      "name": "name_",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "string",
      "name": "symbol_",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "uint8",
      "name": "decimals_",
      "type": "uint8"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "uint256",
      "name": "chainID_",
      "type": "uint256"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "bytes32",
      "name": "realTokenAddress_",
      "type": "bytes32"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "string",
      "name": "chainSymbol_",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
  "type": "constructor"
},
{
  "anonymous": false,
  "inputs": [
    {
      "indexed": true,
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "owner",
      "type": "address"
    },
    {
      "indexed": true,
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "spender",
      "type": "address"
    },
    {
      "indexed": false,
      "internalType": "uint256",
      "name": "value",
      "type": "uint256"
    }
  ],
  "name": "Approval",
  "type": "event"
},
{
  "anonymous": false,
  "inputs": [
    {
      "indexed": true,
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "previousOwner",
      "type": "address"
    },
    {
      "indexed": true,
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "newOwner",
      "type": "address"
    }
  ],
  "name": "OwnershipTransferred",
  "type": "event"
},
{
  "anonymous": false,
  "inputs": [
    {
      "indexed": true,
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "from",
      "type": "address"
    },
    {
      "indexed": true,
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "to",
      "type": "address"
    },
    {
      "indexed": false,
      "internalType": "uint256",
      "name": "value",
      "type": "uint256"
    }
  ],
  "name": "Transfer",
  "type": "event"
},
{
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "DOMAIN_SEPARATOR",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "bytes32",
      "name": "",
      "type": "bytes32"
    }
  ],
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "_chainID",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "uint256",
      "name": "",
      "type": "uint256"
    }
  ],
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "_chainSymbol",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "string",
      "name": "",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "_decimals",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "uint8",
      "name": "",
      "type": "uint8"
    }
  ],
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "_realTokenAddress",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "bytes32",
      "name": "",
      "type": "bytes32"
    }
  ],
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "_tokenName",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "string",
      "name": "",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "owner",
      "type": "address"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "spender",
      "type": "address"
    }
  ],
  "name": "allowance",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "uint256",
      "name": "",
      "type": "uint256"
    }
  ],
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "spender",
      "type": "address"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "uint256",
      "name": "amount",
      "type": "uint256"
    }
  ],
  "name": "approve",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "bool",
      "name": "",
      "type": "bool"
    }
  ],
  "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "account",
      "type": "address"
    }
  ],
  "name": "balanceOf",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "uint256",
      "name": "",
      "type": "uint256"
    }
  ],
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "account",
      "type": "address"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "uint256",
      "name": "amount",
      "type": "uint256"
    }
  ],
  "name": "burn",
  "outputs": [],
  "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "account",
      "type": "address"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "spender",
      "type": "address"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "uint256",
      "name": "amount",
      "type": "uint256"
    }
  ],
  "name": "burnWithAllowanceDecrease",
  "outputs": [],
  "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "decimals",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "uint8",
      "name": "",
      "type": "uint8"
    }
  ],
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "spender",
      "type": "address"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "uint256",
      "name": "subtractedValue",
      "type": "uint256"
    }
  ],
  "name": "decreaseAllowance",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "bool",
      "name": "",
      "type": "bool"
    }
  ],
  "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "getChainId",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "uint256",
      "name": "",
      "type": "uint256"
    }
  ],
  "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "spender",
      "type": "address"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "uint256",
      "name": "addedValue",
      "type": "uint256"
    }
  ],
  "name": "increaseAllowance",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "bool",
      "name": "",
      "type": "bool"
    }
  ],
  "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "account",
      "type": "address"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "uint256",
      "name": "amount",
      "type": "uint256"
    }
  ],
  "name": "mint",
  "outputs": [],
  "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "account",
      "type": "address"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "spender",
      "type": "address"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "uint256",
      "name": "amount",
      "type": "uint256"
    }
  ],
  "name": "mintWithAllowance",
  "outputs": [],
  "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "name",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "string",
      "name": "",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "owner",
      "type": "address"
    }
  ],
  "name": "nonces",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "uint256",
      "name": "",
      "type": "uint256"
    }
  ],
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "owner",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "",
      "type": "address"
    }
  ],
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "owner",
      "type": "address"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "spender",
      "type": "address"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "uint256",
      "name": "value",
      "type": "uint256"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "uint256",
      "name": "deadline",
      "type": "uint256"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "uint8",
      "name": "v",
      "type": "uint8"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "bytes32",
      "name": "r",
      "type": "bytes32"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "bytes32",
      "name": "s",
      "type": "bytes32"
    }
  ],
  "name": "permit",
  "outputs": [],
  "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "renounceOwnership",
  "outputs": [],
  "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "symbol",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "string",
      "name": "",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "totalSupply",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "uint256",
      "name": "",
      "type": "uint256"
    }
  ],
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "recipient",
      "type": "address"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "uint256",
      "name": "amount",
      "type": "uint256"
    }
  ],
  "name": "transfer",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "bool",
      "name": "",
      "type": "bool"
    }
  ],
  "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "sender",
      "type": "address"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "recipient",
      "type": "address"
    },
    {
      "internalType": "uint256",
      "name": "amount",
      "type": "uint256"
    }
  ],
  "name": "transferFrom",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "bool",
      "name": "",
      "type": "bool"
    }
  ],
  "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
  "type": "function"
},
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "internalType": "address",
      "name": "newOwner",
      "type": "address"
    }
  ],
  "name": "transferOwnership",
  "outputs": [],
  "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
  "type": "function"
}
```

]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared your smart contract so I am just gonna make a wild guess. I also encountered the same issue and in my code, the order of the returned `encode_structured_data` wasn't the same as what I have defined in my smart contract. Check what is being returned as `encode_structured_data` and how you defined those in your smart contract (check the struct for this data and also the `_hash` function if you have it. And don't leave any spacing in `_hashTypedDataV4` if you have this also.).

Comment: encode_structured_data returns SignableMessage(version=HexBytes('0x01'), header=b'\xcb1F\xbc}.T\xf6T r2\x16,\xcdT\xf2\x0b\n\x1a\x1d\x07@\xe9\x81#\x91<\x04\x17\xed\xff', body=b'\xd4\x86e\x06\xf9\x84g\xefv\x7f1\xa2\x9c\x96\xb6v\x82?\x81\xb2I\xdc(S\x04\x89\x1f\xfe\xdbI\xa3\xfc')